# what is the difference between triple sat and 3Sat?

Tags: complexity-theory, computation-models

I am trying to grasp the concept of triple sat compared to 3Sat. I understand that 3Sat has 3 literals for each for each clause. ${Triple-Sat} = \{ \phi | \phi $ has at least three satisfying assignments $\}$. Im just not exactly sure what the difference is between them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a connection between the two problems.

3SAT restricts the form or the formulas. A 3SAT formula can have any number of satisfying assignments. 3SAT asks for satisfiability (does there exist a satisfying assignment?)

Triple Sat is independent of the form of the formula, and simply asks a different question (do there exist three different satisfying assignments?)